# Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

**We are facing this issue**

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

```
 btnEdit.setOnClickListener { v ->
                val intent = Intent(v.context, Edit_Logs::class.java)
                v.context.startActivity(intent)
                (v.context as Activity).finish() // Getting Error Here
            }
```

Comment: why did you need to cast context as activity instead using `finish()` ?

Comment: Thank you for replying , finish() is not working  in recycler-view adapter class.

Comment: you can use `ViewHolder`'s itemView context

Comment: @Narasimham: You should delegate the `startActivity` from your Adapter to the parent activity by using Callback.

Comment: @KishoreJethava Thank You , it's working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ViewHolder`'s itemView context